# DAX SUMMARIZECOLUMNS function - How is this function useful?

Tags: dax

According to the DAX Guide (https://dax.guide/summarizecolumns/):

*SUMMARIZECOLUMNS does not support evaluation within a context transition. This makes it not useful in most of the measures*

This function is quite powerful and a nice successor to the SUMMARIZE function. But, I'm a bit curious as to why the DAX team would introduce a function like this when it can only be used in very limited scenarios. I guess if you're wanting to build a calculated table it would be useful. Other than that I think you're pretty much forced to use SUMMARIZE. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Marco Russo, [this limitation has been removed](https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2017/02/02/using-summarizecolumns-instead-of-summarize-in-dax-powerbi-ssas-tabular/) and `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` can be effectively used within measures now in addition to static calculated tables.

There are still a couple of things you need to be aware of if you are looking to switch from `SUMMARIZE` to `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` but Marco covers them in [this article](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-summarizecolumns/)

---

**Edit:** After some testing, it appears I can use it in a measure that is responsive to external filter context (e.g. slicers or page filters) but won't work in the internal filter context produced by a visual (e.g. row/column in a matrix), so the limitation is only partly removed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case. I have never been able to use SUMMARIZECOLUMNS in a measure without getting an error. The article you reference is from 2017. The link in my post was last updated this month. It still contains the disclaimer about its limited use.

Comment: Looks like you are correct. It's only partly resolved. See my edit.

Comment: In your edit I found your use of 'external filter' and 'internal filter' a little confusing. I always thought that any filter context in place outside of DAX was considered an 'external' or 'outer' filter. Any filter applied in DAX, say in a CALCULATE, was considered an 'inner' filter. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's probably not standard usage but I was trying to distinguish between the modified filter context created by the visual and the filter context that applies to the visual. Inside/outside of the visual in this case rather than inside/outside of the measure.

Comment: Also won't except context transition from outside of a bridged table...

Answer (score 4):

`SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` is hugely useful for queries. I am quite certain it was introduced by request of the Power BI team. Almost every visual in PBI generates a query where the bulk of the work is done in a `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS`. These are in the general form of:

```
DEFINE
VAR <filter1> = ...
VAR <filter2> = ...
...
VAR <filterN> = ...
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS
    <grouping columns from visual>,
    <filter1>,
    <filter2>,
    ...,
    <filterN>,
    <measures in visual>
```

In this pattern, all crossfilters from other visuals and all filters in the report are captured in `filter1`, `filter2`, ..., `filterN`. This is a very easy pattern to generate programmatically.

It's also really useful for writing queries in general, as a single function gets you grouping, selection/filtering, and measure evaluation.

Sometimes it's easy to get blinders on, thinking of DAX as a formula language for measures only, but it is a fully fledged relational query language.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my post. The function might be heavily used under the hood. But, for a PBI / DAX developer, it currently has very limited application if you want to use it with the current filter context that comes from a table or matrix or where a context transition is occurring.

Comment: I am, among other things a PBI/DAX developer. I use `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` daily, and for exactly the purpose I mentioned in my answer: writing queries.  You are right that it is not useful in the context of a measure, but your question was "How is the function useful?" I have provided an answer. If you would like a more specific answer, please edit your question or ask a new one.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for your response.