# How to filter SUMMARIZECOLUMNS after crossjoin

Tags: filter, ssas, dax, tabular, ssas-tabular

I am trying to filter the SUMMARIZECOLUMNS by using the CALCULATETABLE, it prompted me an error message:

***"SummarizeColumns can not have outside filter context"***

Is it because of SSAS version, my version is: 13.0.2213.0

```
EVALUATE
CALCULATETABLE(
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        'Product'[Model Name],
        'Product'[Product Line],
        'Product'[Product Name],
        'Customer'[First Name],
        'Customer'[Last Name],
        "Internet Current Quarter Sales", [Internet Current Quarter Sales],
        "Internet Total Sales", [Internet Total Sales]
    ),
    'Internet Sales'[Order Date] > DATEVALUE("1 Jan 2011"),
    OR('Geography'[Country Region Name] = "Australia", 'Geography'[Country Region Name] = "United States")
)
ORDER BY 'Product'[Model Name]
```

I can filter by put the FILTER function inside SUMMARIZECOLUMNS, however it gave me a different result (less records than expected) as the table was filtered before corss-join: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    'Product'[Model Name],
    'Product'[Product Line],
    'Product'[Product Name],
    'Customer'[First Name],
    'Customer'[Last Name],
    FILTER('Internet Sales', [Order Date] > DATEVALUE("1 Jan 2011")),
    FILTER('Geography', [Country Region Name] = "Australia" || [Country Region Name] = "United States"),
    "Internet Current Quarter Sales", [Internet Current Quarter Sales],
    "Internet Total Sales", [Internet Total Sales]
)
ORDER BY 'Product'[Model Name]
```

***filterTable:
A table expression which is added to the filter context of all columns specified as groupBy_columnName arguments. The values present in the filter table are used to filter before cross-join/auto-exist is performed.***

Any idea how to achive the filter same as CALCULATETABLE function? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57691355/dax-summarizecolumns-function-how-is-this-function-useful

Comment: Thank RADO, is there any other way to achieve outside filter context in SUMMARIZECOLUMNS without upgrade SSAS version?

Comment: summarize + addcolumns pattern?